# What does it mean for a sum of two subspaces to be equivalent to the entire space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\mathbb{R^3}$ and let $W_1=$span$\{(1,1,0),(1,0,0)\}$ and $W_2=$span$\{(0,1,0),(0,1,1)\}$. Does $V=W_1+W_2$? Is $V$ the direct sum of $W_1$ and $W_2$?

I have been able to show that taking any arbitrary $v\in V$ where $v=(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ we can deconstruct it into:
$$ v=(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\alpha(1,0,0)+\beta[(1,1,0)-(1,0,0)]+\gamma[(0,1,1)-(0,1,0)] $$
$$\quad =(\alpha,\beta,0)+(0,0,\gamma)  $$
where $(\alpha,\beta,0)\in W_1$ and $(0,0,\gamma)\in W_2$. Therfore, the sum $W_1+W_2$ is a generating set for $\mathbb{R^3}$. My confusion, I believe, is with the wording of the questions. Clearly, I could've deconstructed $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ in a different way constructing $(0,\beta,0$) from a linear combination of $W_2$. So does this mean that $V=W_1+W_2$ but it is not the direct sum of the two since they lack a unique representation.

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct. The equality $V = W_1 + W_2$ holds like you have shown, but the sum is not direct, since there isn't a unique way to decompose an arbitrary $v \in V$ into a sum of some $w_1 \in W_1$ and $w_2 \in W_1$. An equivalent way of showing the sum is direct, would be to consider whether the intersection $W_1 \cap W_2$ is trivial, which in our case it isn't, because $W_1 \cap W_2 = \text{span}\{(0,1,0)\}$, leading us to the same conclusion.

Comment: So this means that $V=W_1+W_2$. However, $V$ is not the direct sum of $W_1$ and $W_2$ since elements in $V$ can be written in multiple different ways using elements of $W_1$ and $W_2$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.